# Добавление названий всех столбцов в listbox из MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

Хочу загрузить в listBox название всех столбцов, где то я ошибся либо не дописал код. Слабоват в MySql. Ничего не загружает

```
    private async void INSERT_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await LoadStudentsAsync();

    }


    private async Task LoadStudentsAsync() //Выбор
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();


        DataTable tables = new DataTable("Tables");


        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Students", sqlConnection);
        try
        {
                tables.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                foreach (DataRow row in tables.Rows)
                listBox1.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Ответ от пользователя - Anatol вызывает ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
private async Task LoadStudentsAsync() //Выбор
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

         MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Students", sqlConnection);
         try
         {
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            DataTable schema = sqlConnection.GetSchema("Columns");
            foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows) 
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(row.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME"));
            }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         }
 }
```

Comment: В вашем коде `command` совершенно лишний. Можно убрать обе строки.

Comment: `GetSchema("Columns")` вернёт информацию обо _всех_ колонках в базе данных. Если у вас всего одна таблица, то результат устроит. Если таблиц несколько, то следует использовать перегрузку метода `GetSchema`, принимающую два параметра.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Petrov одна, буду знать :D

Answer (score 0):

Потому что ваш запрос получает данные всей таблицы, а не имена столбцов. Попробуйте так:

```
   private async Task LoadStudentsAsync() //Выбор
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' AND `TABLE_NAME`='Students';", sqlConnection);
        try
        {
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString()); 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

И да, зачем там `DataTable`? В данном примере можно прекрасно обойтись без него.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как сделать

Comment: что именно сделать?

Comment: Зачем нам брать WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename'  когда у нас уже есть подключение к этой базе данных

Comment: У меня вообще ничего не получается, вы говорите убрать DataTable, а что дописать я не знаю так много о C#

Comment: как-то так, обновил

Comment: и если что-то не получается, то надо хотя бы объяснить что именно

Comment: щас скрин приложу

Comment: я извиняюсь, а вы вместо _yourdatabasename_ подставили имя своей бд?

Comment: да я подписал имя своей бд

Comment: И да у вас кавычки вызовут ошибку синтаксиса если что к слову

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Petrov ошибаетесь , мне как раз нужны названия всех столбцов, и их добавить в listbox1

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov гоните шекель )

Comment: не ужели так сложно решить вопрос (((

Comment: какой вопрос? вопрос "_как получить имена столбцов_" решён

Comment: да у меня ошибка как бы по вашему методу возникает