# Добавляются столбцы в listbox1 из всей базы данных почему то, хотя нужно только с таблицы Students

Tags: c#, mysql

Добавляются столбцы из всей базы данных почему то, хотя нужно только с таблицы Students.

```
  MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Students", sqlConnection);
            try
            {
                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                DataTable schema = sqlConnection.GetSchema("Columns");
                foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(row.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME"));
                }
            }
```

Comment: [_Ты зачем усы сбрил, дурик?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56120661/5045688) Не надо аккаунты дублировать.

Comment: Я ж писал комментарий [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/980341/184217). Используйте перегрузку метода с двумя параметрами.

Comment: 1 запрос на ютубе,20 минут на видео и решение у вас

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Petrov там можно задавать 1 вопрос если шо. И какие два параметра принимать и как

Comment: @TEA я посмотрел видео 60 минут, решения нету !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
{
    string[] restrictions = new string[4] { null, null, "Students", null };
    DataTable schema = sqlConnection.GetSchema("Columns", restrictions); 
    foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(row.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME"));
    }
}
```